# Application Received memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on a news application based on xml parsing. For long time Facing application memory warning issue which crashes app, xcode shows memory usages more then 400MB and app getting crashed. Its a critical issue and i don't know how to rectify it.

Comment: We need more info for this. Please profile the app and provide more info and some code, so we can be of help

Comment: Not  able to identify which part of code is responsible for it. Most of UI part is also managed by code and recreated between screen transitions.

Comment: @jagdish, just use instrument to identify the exact issue...

Comment: With your project open in Xcode do Product>Profile. Then choose allocations and run your app for a while and observe memory footprint

Answer (score 0):

Try your Application with Xcode - > Open Developer tool instrument--> memory allocation

It tell memory using by app & show issue or league

Use of large size of image

Did you creating objects and holding on to them with a strong reference for longer than you need to.

Need Code better answer.